# Group by Lengths of Lists

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, gathering

Let’s say, we have a list of lists:

```
Table[0, {30}, RandomInteger[{1, 5}]]
```

which might look like this

```
{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0}, {0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0}, {0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0}, {0, 0, 0}}
```

My function now groups the lists so that each group contains not more than 10 elements if the group gets flattened once. In this case it results in:

```
{{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0}, {0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0}, {0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0}}, {{0, 0, 0}}}
```

With group lengths of `{10, 9, 10, 9, 10, 8, 9, 9, 3}`.

I am asking myself, if there is a better way to implement it.

```
RegroupWithListLength[list_, limit_: 10] := Block[
  {result = {{}}},
  Do[If[
    Length[Flatten[result[[-1]], 1]] + Length[list[[i]]] <= limit,
    AppendTo[result[[-1]], list[[i]]],
    AppendTo[result, {list[[i]]}]],
   {i, Length[list]}];
  result
  ]
```

$\tiny\textit{For the code golfers around ... in my small world, this might be a nice challenge, no?}$

Comment: If it's code golf you want, can we come up with a language where this task is accomplished by the code `‹νφ«§_^CLX-IχＡ`?

Comment: @JasonB., but then you can come up w/ another language to code this particular program as a single character.

Comment: I'm almost certain this is a duplicate, but I can't for the life of me find it.

Comment: Oh wait, is it [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102900/grouping-by-total-length-of-elements-grouped)?

Answer (score 6):

A simpler solution using [`FoldPairList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldPairList.html)

```
f[n_, x_, size_] := 
  If[n - Length[x] < 0, {x, size - Length[x]}, {x, n - Length[x]}];
groupElementsBySize[lst_, size_] := Split[FoldPairList[f[#1, #2, size] &, size, lst, Identity], 
   Last[#1] - Last[#2] > 0 &] // Apply[#1 &, #, {2}] &
```

**Test:**

```
groupElementsBySize[list, 10]
```

> {{{0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 
>      0}}, {{0, 0}, {0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0}, {0}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
>       0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
>      0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
>      0}, {0, 0}}, {{0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}}}

**Timing comparison:**

```
SeedRandom[42];
tab = Table[0, 10^5, RandomInteger[{1, 5}]];
res1 = RegroupWithListLength2[tab, 10];// RepeatedTiming
res2 = groupElementsBySize[tab, 10];// RepeatedTiming
res1==res2
```

> {0.46, Null}
>
> {0.880, Null}
>
> True

Answer (score 5):

This is just using `Reap/Sow` instead of `AppendTo` - with a very mild gain in performance

```
RegroupWithListLength[list_List, limit_: 10] := 
 Block[{i = 0, currentTotal = 0, len},
  Reap[
    Scan[
     (len = Length@#;
       If[currentTotal + len <= limit,
        currentTotal += len;
        Sow[#, i],
        currentTotal = len;
        Sow[#, ++i]
        ]) &
     ,
     list
     ]
    ][[2]]
  ]
```

Answer (score 5):

I just had the same Idea as Jason B, but didn't see his post until I finished testing my version. I post it anyway, since it is slightly different:

```
ClearAll[RegroupWithListLength2]

RegroupWithListLength2::bdlen = 
  "The list `1` contains a list which is longer than `2`.";

RegroupWithListLength2[list_, limit_: 10] := 
 Module[{count = 0, bin = 0},
   Last@Reap[
     (
         If[(count += Length[#]) > limit, bin++; count = Length[#]];
         Sow[#, bin];
     ) & /@ list;
    ]
   ] /; If[Max[Length /@ list] > limit, 
      Message[RegroupWithListLength2::bdlen, Short[list], limit]; False, 
      True
     ]
```

For long lists the performance increase is significant:

```
SeedRandom[42];
With[{
  tab = Table[0, 10^5, RandomInteger[{1, 5}]],
  n = 10
  },
 First@RepeatedTiming[RegroupWithListLength[tab, n]]
 ]
(* 8.5 *)

SeedRandom[42];
With[{
  tab = Table[0, 10^5, RandomInteger[{1, 5}]],
  n = 10
  },
 First@RepeatedTiming[RegroupWithListLength2[tab, n]]
 ]
(* 0.942 *)
```

I also added the `/;` test at the end of my function definition so it does not evaluate if one of the lists is shorter than the limit.

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting this, not because it's fast (it isn't), but because I like recursion.

Test case data

```
data = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0}, {0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0}, {0, 0,0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0,0}, {0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0}, {0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0}, {0, 0, 0}};
```

Test case results

```
grouped = {{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0}, {0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0}, {0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0}}, {{0, 0,0}}};
```

Recursive function solution based on the principal-helper design pattern.

```
grouper[items:{{__} ..}, Optional[limit_Integer?Positive, 10]] := 
  helper[items, limit, {}, {}]

helper[{}, _, grps_, grp_] := Join[new, {grp}]
helper[{item_, rest___}, limit_, new_, grp_] :=
  If[Total[Length /@ grp] + Length @ item <= limit,
    helper[{rest}, limit, grps_, Join[grp, {item}]],
    helper[{rest}, limit, Join[grps_, {grp}], {item}]]

grouper[data] == grouped
```

> `True`

#### Update

One very good reason for using the principal-helper design pattern when writing recursive code is that it allows the principal function to do heavy duty argument checking before calling the helper function the carries out the recursion. Since the principal function is only called once, the time-cost of argument checking is not too great. If no helper was used, the argument checking could become very expensive because it would done over and over again.

Here is `grouper` upgraded to near industrial grade argument checking.

```
Clear[grouper]
grouper::toolong = "`1` is longer than the length limit `2`";
grouper[items : {{__} ..}, Optional[limit_Integer?Positive, 10]] := 
  Check[
    Do[If[Length[i] > limit, Message[grouper::toolong, i, limit]], {i, items}];
    helper[items, limit, {}, {}],
    $Failed,
    {grouper::toolong}]
```